# Creating a directory using part of a variable name

Tags: python, mkdir, os.path

New to python and Im trying to create a set of directories, and create a file in each one, the input name will be a string starting with a > sign but I don't want the directory to contain the >.

I've tried to do the following;

```
    seq_id = ">seq"
    dirname = seq_id[1:]

    print(dirname)
    if not os.path.isdir('./' + dirname + '/'):
       os.mkdir('./' + dirname + '/')

    print("directory made")
```

It will not make the directory when I used the seq_id[1:] bit but it will print it. So I don't really get why it won't create the directory.

I ultimately want to build a function that would take a list of seq_ids from a file, >seq1 >seq2 >seq3 etc and create a directory for each one.

(Working with python3.5)

Comment: can not replicate, works for me

Comment: Please, add any error messages you get to the question.

Comment: So I don't get an error, 

It prints the dirname and returns process finished with exit code 0. 

but the directory hasnt been created.

Answer (score 0):

You must know the directories will be created at your *current directory position*.

If you are in folder `/tmp/foo/`, your script in `/tmp/bar/myscript.py` and you execute it with `python ../bar/myscript.py` the directories will be created in `/tmp/foo/`, not `/tmp/bar/`.

More of that, because you just skip possible errors with `if not os.path.isdir('./' + dirname + '/'):` and never prints nothing, you will not know if directory already exists.

You could do something like:

```
import os

strings = ['>foo', '>bar', '>baz']

def make_directories(input_list):
    for string in input_list:
        dirpath = os.path.join('./', string[1:])
        try:
            os.mkdir(dirpath)
        except FileExistsError:
            print('Directory {} already exists'.format(dirpath))
        else:
            print('Directory {} created'.format(dirpath))

make_directories(strings)
```

1. It uses `os.path.join` instead of homemade concatenation. It's a best practice you should always follow.
2. It uses `try` / `except` instead of `if`, again it's a best practice you should follow ([Reference](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-eafp))
3. It prints things, so you know what is going on.